# Java 8 VM.native_memory

Tags: java, out-of-memory, metaspace

I'm having hard times with java 8 metaspace memory management. I'm currently using jdk 1.8_60 on RHEL.

this is my tomcat classpath:

```
/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/apache/tomcat/apache-tomcat/conf/logging.properties
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Xms1g
-Xmx16g
-XX:MetaspaceSize=128m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary
-Dorg.apache.cxf.stax.allowInsecureParser=1
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/apache/tomcat/apache-tomcat/temp/heap.dump
-Xloggc:/opt/apache/tomcat/apache-tomcat/logs/gc.log
-XX:+PrintGC
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:GCLogFileSize=5m
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=20
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9998
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/apache/tomcat/apache-tomcat/endorsed
-classpath /opt/apache/tomcat/apache-tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache/tomcat/apache-tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
-Dcatalina.base=/opt/apache/tomcat/apache-tomcat
-Dcatalina.home=/opt/apache/tomcat/apache-tomcat
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/apache/tomcat/apache-tomcat/temp
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

When I execute the `jcmd <PID> VM.native_memory summary.diff` it's showing that reserved memory for Class (what I believe is metaspace size) is more than 256m (looks like default 1g).

```
-                 Java Heap (reserved=16777216KB, committed=5485568KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=16777216KB, committed=5485568KB)

-                     Class (reserved=1149430KB, committed=112886KB)
                            (classes #16384 +1)
                            (malloc=6646KB #23800)
                            (mmap: reserved=1142784KB, committed=106240KB)

-                    Thread (reserved=32005KB -2065KB, committed=32005KB -2065KB)
                            (thread #32 -2)
                            (stack: reserved=31868KB -2056KB, committed=31868KB -2056KB)
                            (malloc=101KB -7KB #161 -10)
                            (arena=36KB -2 #62 -4)
```

I'm using cxf [dynamic client](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/dynamic-clients.html) for dynamic WS call, so each call is generating significant amount of classes, but it looks like this classes are never removed from metaspace (even if I click on button perform gc inside jvisualvm). At the end metaspace is full and application ends with **OutOfMemoryException: Metaspace**

I've also used GC1 with this config `-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+AggressiveOpts` but that didn't helped me.

So is it possible that there is bug in jvm which displays misconfigured memory allocation for metaspace (or worse it it uses this value to manage metaspace)? Can somebody point me to some direction how to solve problem with metaspace cleanup?

many thanks